# Is the check for zero needed in this case (after modulus and addition)?

Tags: java, collections, int, modulo

If I have e.g. `int size` and contains e.g. the size of a list then having `int distance` the `mod` operation i.e. `distance%size` is `(-size - 1) <= distance <= (size - 1)`

I.e. distance will always be among this range `(-size - 1) <= distance <= (size - 1)`

If I am correct on this then what is the meaning of the following condition check in [CollectionsRotate in JDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.rotate1%28java.util.List,int%29)?

```
 if (size == 0)
    return;  
 distance = distance % size;  
if (distance < 0)  
   distance += size;  
if (distance == 0)  //Why this check????
    return;
```

I may be wrong or rusty here, but I don't think that `distance` at this point can ever be null as a result of the addition. And if the list was `0` we would not reach that condition in the first place.
So is this conditional check needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if `distance == n * size` (n an int) then `distance%size == 0`. For example if `distance == 0` or `distance == size`.

Comment: And here I thought I was going crazy with all the strange answers. Quite obviously distance can easily be 0 here.

Comment: +1 if `distance == n * size` where n can be negative or positive,  the modulus is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's the `if (distance < 0)` but distance could be `0` as well, thus skipping 
`distance += size;`. Hence the check for `distance == 0`.

You could also write the code using  `else if`:

```
//if distance is < 0, distance + size can't be 0 (due to the modulo before)
//however, distance could be 0 at this point if distance was 0 before or became 0 due to the modulo
if (distance < 0)  
   distance += size;  
else if (distance == 0)  //Why this check????
   return;
```

Answer (score 0):

If size is 5 and distance is 0, the addition will never be done and distance will be zero when it hits the check.